# Bug with using whitespace to signal end of string

Tags: c, input, whitespace

I am working on a program that does the following: read user's input, and split the strings into smaller strings that are separated by whitespace and print them in separate lines; for example, if the user input AB CD, then I should print

```
AB
CD
```

Right now my approach is to scan in one character at a time. If that character is not a whitespace, then I collect it into a string (which can happen multiple times). If that character is a whitespace, then print out the string that is collected. But when I input echo -n (with inputs), my last string collected is not printed because there is no whitespace. Is there anything I can do to solve this problem with little adjustments or is my approach completely wrong? Thank you

My code is the following (I abbreviate it a bit, my original program qualifies the character and the function returns -1 if it is not the character A)

```
int main(void)
{
    int t = 1;
    char a;
    char pattern_collected[5001];
    int l = 0;

    while (t == scanf("%c", &a)) {
        if (isspace(a)) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
                printf("%c", pattern_collected[i])
            }
            l = 0;
            memset(pattern_collected, 0x00, 5001);
        } else {
            pattern_collected[l] = 'A';
            l++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to detect the end of the line, which usually *is* a white-space character. Yes, newline is a space. `isspace('\n')` will give you a "true" value.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I guess you are using some sort of while loop. After the while loop finishes, print that string variable (which contains the last string).

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please post actual, compilable code, not something that only resembles the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but I think the problem is when I use echo -n instead of echo to redirect the input, echo -n lacks the newline that allows the last string to print

Comment: `l` is not initialized.

Comment: @stark thank you I forgot to include that, i am not used to copy stuff from emacs to win

Comment: Have you even tried compiling that code?

Comment: You have a bunch of strange requirements. What are you trying to solve? It sounds like you just want `echo` except replace all whitespace with `'\n'`.

Comment: This `pattern_collected[l] = 'A';` doesn't seem right.  Don't you want to save the value in `a`?

Comment: What does `echo` and `echo -n` have to do with this program? Are you piping the output of  `echo` to this program? Then the end of the output from `echo` will be an end-of-file and `scanf` returning `0`.

Comment: By the way, the loop `for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)` will go out of "bounds" of the initialized part of the array. The condition needs to be `i < l`.

Answer (score 1):

If your loops breaks because there is nothing left to `scanf()`, you need to check `l`. If it's not 0, the input misses the final whitespace, and then print what is collected in `pattern_collected`.